# Remove css from div on server side C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

i have a div tag which has inline css whose visibility is hidden

```
 <div id="SecondGrid" runat="server" style="width:80%; margin-left:10%; visibility:hidden;">
//content
</div>
```

i have a button in gridview, on click of which i want to remove the visibility css of the above div

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ShowCarModels")
        {
            CarBrandID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            BindGridView2(CarBrandID);
            SecondGrid.Style.Remove("visibility");

        }
    }
```

the div still appear to be hidden. can you please help me out.

Comment: The Button calling postback?

Comment: no button is not postback

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333570/remove-css-class-in-code-behind

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Visible` property. As you use your html control at server side you can use Visible property for show or hide control.

```
SecondGrid.Visible = true;
```

For above solution you need to change you html markup to follwing

```
<div id="SecondGrid" runat="server" visible="false" style="width:80%; margin-left:10%;">
//content
</div>
```

but if you want to continue with your markup you can also remove style using `HtmlTextWriterStyle`

```
SecondGrid.Style.Remove(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility);
```

Comment: No its still not working. i think one cant alter css in 'GridView1_RowCommand' function. :(

Comment: Did you debug the code, when click on button goes to that line to set Visible to true?

Comment: yea did the debug. it executes the line but css 'Visibility' does not alter

Comment: set the AutoPostBack="true"  for the button within grid. still doesn't work

Comment: As @Manish mentioned, should remove 'Visibility' from Html code and just adding Visible='false', then in your code only set the Visible=true. Don't need alter the Style

Comment: i actually wanted to keep the space intact of the hidden element because of which i had to put visibility:hidden css.

Answer (score -1):

dint found the reason as why none of the css style alteration were not working under 'GridView1_RowCommand' but found a work around for my solution. Just wanted to share.

have put the css in a class

```
  .SecondG 
        {
            visibility:hidden;
        }
```

assigned the class to div

```
  <div id="SecondGrid" runat="server" style="width:80%; margin-left:10%; padding:20px; border:1px solid #E6E6E6;" class="SecondG" >
```

created a javascript to remove the class from the div

```
  function ShowModel()
        {
               var d = document.getElementById("<%=SecondGrid.ClientID%>");
               d.className = "";

        }
```

called the above javascript function on button click in the grid.

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Models" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="img_Save" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowModel()" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CarBrandID") %>' CommandName="ShowCarModels" Width="100%"  Text="Display Models"  />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and its working. thanks a lot guys for the help..

Comment: The question is how to remove Css on the serve side. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333570/remove-css-class-in-code-behind