# how to remove a class name from entire page asp.net c#

Tags: c#

My codes is like

```
<th runat="server" id="thTodayToTenTotal" class="redRow">  
<th runat="server" id="thTodayToTenTotal" class="redRow">
```

I remove the attribute class="redRow" like that  from CodeBehind

```
thTodayToTenTotal.Attributes.Remove("class");
```

It is OK.

But the class "redRow" can have many in my page. How to remove this class name from entire page one time. Then I want to add this class to one html element.I means that I have

```
<th runat="server" id="wantToAddClass">
```

I add the class from CodeBehind like that

```
wantToAddClass.Attributes.Add("class", "redRow");
```

Comment: Can you explain in details

Comment: Please see my edited question. Thanks Satish Patil.

Comment: are you open to Jquery solution ?

Comment: pretty sure you want to loop through the collection of controls

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with jQuery, which would be:

```
$(document).ready (function ({
     var elements = $(".redRow");
     $.each (elements, function(index) {
          elements[index].removeAttr("class");
     });
});
```

Then problem, unless from a server side control where you can anchor to the event, you wouldn't know which element to remove.  Since an id is one per page.  Otherwise you'd be trying to parse an html page, Javascript is more than likely ideal.

Comment: Can someone format code, mobile phone isn't allowing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please tell me how to add this class to one html element. My question is edited. Please see Greg.Thanks.

Comment: sorry greg, but we have no option to edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As CRise commented, you have to loop all web controls and find each control which has class you wanted.

Let me give you some help here.

Lets Create one Utility method.

```
IEnumerable<Control> FindControl( Control c, Func<Control,bool> predicate )
{
    if( predicate( c ) )
        yield return c;

    foreach (var child in c.Controls) {
        if (predicate((Control)child)) {
           yield return (Control)child;
        }
    }

    foreach( var child in c.Controls )
        foreach( var match in FindControl( (Control)child, predicate ) )
           yield return match;
}
```

And then call these method wherever you want to check for your class.

```
foreach(WebControl c in FindControl( Page, c => (c is WebControl) && 
                       ((WebControl)c).CssClass == "redRow" ))
{
     //Do your operation.
}
```

for further details there are lots of questions already asked in SO. see.

[How to select an element by Class instead of ID in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766408/how-to-select-an-element-by-class-instead-of-id-in-asp-net)

[remove css class in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333570/remove-css-class-in-code-behind)

You can use JavaScript or Jquery too.

Comment: If you do this via code behind, it will be incredibly slow.  Since every aspect of the page is considered a control.

Comment: @Greg: ya, you're right but i have to answer in only C# and code behind, and you have already answered in JQuery, so we can suggest user to use scripting languages but it always depends on requirement..

Comment: I know, just encouraging op not to do it unless he has to, but rethink the solution.